# Can I send git commit emails to multiple recipients?

Tags: git, email

I am using git's default post-receive-email hook. Is it possible to configure the script to send notifications to multiple emails?

Please note that I do *not* want to use a mailing list. My project has only 2 developers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the script, it appears that the value of `git config hooks.mailinglist` is used directly in the `To:` field of the outgoing message. So, simply add more than one email address separated by commas into `git config hooks.mailinglist`.